# Frequent peaks of CPU, caused by unknown java process

Tags: java, cpu, cpu-load

For some hours, I experience frequent peaks in the CPU usage of my laptop, due to a java process I don't know about, even if it is run by in my session (see firt line below).

[image]

Peaks occur irregularly (about every 5 minutes) and last about 20 seconds. I am not doing anything special when they occur (actually typing some text in  [TeXstudio](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/texstudio/)). It continues even after having rebooted my system.

How could I narrow down the cause of this issue?

*Edit:* Thanks to [Andrew's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/897930/498358), I've found that the peaks are cause by `/proc/4146/exe -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`... but I'm not sure what triggers it.

Comment: Press `c` in `top` to see the full command, then use the right arrow to see more about the command. It'll probably include the name of the Java class that's being executed. You can alternatively run `ps aux | fgrep java`.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Thanks! Indeed, running `top -o PID` (to sort processes by ID) and then hitting `C` easily led me to incriminate LanguageTool for an issue [previously reported](http://forum.languagetool.org/t/100-cpu-utilization-with-ubuntu-12-04-java-1-7-and-languagetool-stable-oxt/53). Could you please write an answer that I'd be pleased to accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `top`, you can press <kbd>c</kbd> to show the whole command, then use <kbd>→</kbd> to see more about the command, which will probably include the name of the Java class that's being executed.

Results are sorted by their CPU use (`%CPU`). If you want to sort results otherwise, you can run `top -o <name of the colum>` (e.g. `top -o PID` to sort by process ID, or `top -o %MEM` to sort processes by the amount of memory used).

You can alternatively run `ps aux | fgrep java` to see all running `java` processes.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo ls -l /proc/PID/exe
```

Will show you where it is located, which will help locate the app in question.

Answer (score 2):

I spent awhile trying to track down a similar process that was using all of my CPU. If you have been using docker recently on your local machine, make sure to check whether the process that is using all your CPU is coming from docker.

```
sudo docker container ls` to see running containers
```

Run

```
sudo docker stop <container-name>
```

to stop it and

```
sudo docker rm <container-name>
```

to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where my CPU usage by java went more than 100%, I was running Eclipse IDE on on Ubuntu and there was build process started on Ubuntu which caused this issue.

Build process was running on background for too many files which caused java to use CPU more than 100%. when i stopped the build process it cools down and came to normal.

Then I setup a custom build settings for the project from Eclipse IDE menu

```
Project > Build working set  > Select Working Set
```

now create a custom build working set and ignore the directory having too many files which you do not need to build then select that New Working Set for the project.

Hope it helps someone.